# Passing parameter to custom policy in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm developing an app and I need to implement custom authorization policy.
Scenario: user can make GET request only on companies in which is employed.

So far I came up with code enclosed below. What I don't like about it is getting `companyId` parameter that way `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData()?.Values["companyId"]` in authorization policy because it may be tricky to change `companyId` parameter name in the future as it won't be visible at controller's side that this parameter is also used in authorization policy.
Is there a better way to do it?

```
        [HttpGet("{companyId}")]
        [Authorize(Policy = "UserEmployedInCompany")]
        public ActionResult<CompanyReadDto> GetOne(int companyId)
        {
            var company = _repository.GetRepository<Company>().Get(companyId);
            if (company == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return _mapper.Map<CompanyReadDto>(company);
        }
```

```
        protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
          UserEmployedInCompanyRequirement requirement)
        {
            var companyIdFromRoute = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData()?.Values["companyId"].ToString(); ;
            int companyId = 0;
            if (companyIdFromRoute is null || !int.TryParse(companyIdFromRoute, out companyId))
            {
                context.Fail();
            }
            var company = _repository.GetRepository<Company>()
                .Find(x => x.Id == companyId, x => x.Employees).FirstOrDefault();
            var currentUser = await _manager.GetUserAsync(context.User);

            if (company != null && company.Employees.Exists(x => x.User == currentUser))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Are you using claims in authentication? If so, you can add companyId to the `ClaimsPrincipal` on the user and check it there.

Comment: You are actually doing it the right way, according to REST. Since the company is the resource being requested, its Id should always be in the route. Unfortunately you're right - since they are strings you will not have type safety if the parameter is renamed. For a more generic/robust approach, just name all Ids for all resources "id" (instead of "companyId") - that would guard against this type of thing and allow you to (potentially) reuse your policies in a more generic way.